# TypeScript utility to union multiple types that each intersect to a single "base" type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript2.0

When I have a type property that requires another property in the type to be a specific value, my types become overly complex. I'd like to write a utility type that abstracts the logic.

Example. Say I write a type that relates to a Text (React) component I'm building:

```
type Props = {
  children: React.ReactNode; // Just a React type, not pertinent to the question
  as: "p" | "span" | "h1" | "h2" | "h3" | "h4" | "h5" | "h6"; // The html tag for the text
  truncate?: boolean; // Whether to truncate the text when it is long
  expanded?: boolean; // The truncated text is expanded when this is true
  bigHeading?: boolean; // When `as` is `"h1" | "h2" | "h3" | "h4" | "h5" | "h6"`, this property makes a normal heading extra large.
}
```

`expanded?` doesn’t do anything unless `truncate?` is `true`, and `bigHeading?` doesn’t do anything unless `as` is `"h1" | "h2" | "h3" | "h4" | "h5" | "h6"`. So, I want the `Props` type to disallow `expanded` and `bigHeading` unless those conditions are met.

The way I go about it is this:

```
type BaseProps = {
  children: React.ReactNode;
};

type NoTruncateProps = BaseProps & {
  as: "p" | "span";
  truncate?: false;
};

type TruncateProps = BaseProps & {
  as: "p" | "span";
  truncate: true;
  expanded?: boolean;
};

type NoTruncateHeadingProps = BaseProps & {
  as: "h1" | "h2" | "h3" | "h4" | "h5" | "h6";
  bigHeading?: boolean;
  truncate?: false;
};

type TruncateHeadingProps = BaseProps & {
  as: "h1" | "h2" | "h3" | "h4" | "h5" | "h6";
  bigHeading?: boolean;
  truncate: true;
  expanded?: boolean;

};

type Props = NoTruncateProps | TruncateProps | NoTruncateHeadingProps | TruncateHeadingProps
```

This is obviously overly complex. How would I simplify and abstract this logic away for re-usability?

Related: [TypeScript utility type for conditional props (based on entered value of other properties in the type)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56437759/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logic in this type is pretty complex so either way you put it the type is going to be pretty complex. The approach I would use is to break down each piece of logic in a separate type and then intersect them.

For `truncate` and `expanded` we would get:

```
  type Truncatable = {
    truncate: true;
    expanded?: boolean
  } | {
    truncate?: false;
  }
```

For `as` and `bigHeading` we would get:

```
type HeadingOrText = {
    as: "p" | "span"
} | {
    as: "h1" | "h2" | "h3" | "h4" | "h5" | "h6";
    bigHeading?: boolean;
}
```

We can then intersect them to get the final union we want. There is one complication though with excess property checks that is outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52677576/typescript-discriminated-union-allows-invalid-state/52678379#52678379) and we will use the solution presented there. We can also use the `Id` type to flatten out the props for nicer errors and tool-tips:

```
type UnionKeys<T> = T extends any ? keyof T : never;
type StrictUnionHelper<T, TAll> = T extends any ? T & Partial<Record<Exclude<UnionKeys<TAll>, keyof T>, never>> : never;
type StrictUnion<T> = StrictUnionHelper<T, T>

type Id<T> = {} & { [P in keyof T]: T[P] }

type Truncateable = {
    truncate: true;
    expanded?: boolean
} | {
    truncate?: false;
}
type HeadingOrText = {
    as: "p" | "span"
} | {
    as: "h1" | "h2" | "h3" | "h4" | "h5" | "h6";
    bigHeading?: boolean;
}

type WithChildren = {
    children: React.ReactNode;
}
type Props = Id<StrictUnion<HeadingOrText & WithChildren & Truncateable>>

let h1: Props = {
    as: "h1",
    bigHeading: true,
    truncate: true,
    expanded: false,
    children: []
}


let hErr: Props = {
    as: "h1",
    bigHeading: true,
    truncate: false,
    expanded: false, // causes error
    children: []
}



let p: Props = { // ok
    as: "p",
    children: []
}

let pErr: Props = {
    as: "p",
    children: [],
    bigHeading: true // causes error
}
```

While not necessarily less code I think this solution composes well and allows the addition of other mixin-like types to the union.